# Spread operator overwriting elements in new object instead of combining

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalizr

I'm getting data from my API, and passing it through normalizr before dumping it into redux. When I get people data from the API the reducer should append them to the people store. Right now my reducer is overwriting all existing data in the store.

The reducer:

```
export default function reducer(state={
    people: {
        entities : {
          people: {
            0 : {
              name : ''
            }
          }
        },
        result : [0,]
    }
  }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_PEOPLE": {
      const newpPeople = {...state.people, ...action.payload };
      console.log(state.people)
      console.log(action.payload)
      console.log(newpPeople)
      return {...state, people : newpPeople};
    }
    default :
      return state
  }
}
```

This first console log is the state after the reducer has been used once. it has the initial set of people that i've saved to the store:

```
{ 
    entities: { 
                people : { 
                          1 : { id: 1, name: "jim" },
                          2 : { id: 2, name: "billy" }
                         }
              },
    result : [ 1, 2 ]
}
```

The second console log will be the payload of new people to be added:

```
{ 
    entities: { 
                people : { 
                          7 : { id: 7, name: "sally" },
                          8 : { id: 8, name: "ana" }
                         }
              },
    result : [ 7, 8 ]
}
```

Then the third console log should be the two states combined? But it just repeats the last one with sally and ana, and overwrites everything else.

Comment: Because your state is coming from default value which you have passed as argument of that function.

Comment: Check this code for more details https://github.com/sandyjoshi/react-redux-hello-meetup/blob/master/src/utils/index.js & https://github.com/sandyjoshi/react-redux-hello-meetup/blob/master/src/reducers/wish.js

Comment: Can you elaborate? The default state is only used when the store is initialized. When I dispatch an action the payload overwrites that default code with the code in my example console logs, so the default code is only there in the beginning

Comment: I will look at your examples. thank you

Comment: What is the output from the first two console.logs() exactly? The entities code snippet is just confusing. It looks like entities is a nested object of state.people from the way you posted it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because spread will not combine the objects recursively.

Take a look at this simple example where it works as you expected:

```js
const state = { 
        entities: { 
                    people : { 
                              1 : { id: 1, name: "jim" },
                              2 : { id: 2, name: "billy" }
                             }
                  },
        result : [ 1, 2 ]
    }
    
    const payload = { 
        entities: { 
                    people : { 
                              7 : { id: 7, name: "sally" },
                              8 : { id: 8, name: "ana" }
                             }
                  },
        result : [ 7, 8 ]
    }
    
    const new_state = { 
        entities: { 
                    people : { 
                              ...state.entities.people,...payload.entities.people
                             }
                  },
        result : [...state.result,...payload.result]
    }
    
    console.log(new_state)
```

Comment: This is getting me on the right track, and has me moving forward. Is that really the best approach? Are there any tools that can handle this better? The people key isn't the only entity. As I add other entities it becomes far more complex to handle.

Comment: You can use reducer composition, where each reducer receives just a slice of the state, the slice it needs to change. The official doc has a good example http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

Comment: I'm going to mark you as correct. The answer is I need to go deep in spreading every sub object. The only thing I needed to change is using lodash.uniq wrapped around results because sometimes there was duplicate key values. Thank you very much. I'm able to move forward.

Comment: To follow on from this answer: I'd encourage you to read through the [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section of the Redux docs, particularly the [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) page.